# how to structure a python function that take input from data frame to calculate specific indicator

Tags: python, dataframe, indicator

I'm a beginner python coder, I want to build a python function that calculate a specific indicator,

as example, the data is look like:

```
ID    status        Age    Gender
01    healthy       16     Male
02    un_healthy    14     Female
03    un_healthy    22     Male
04    healthy       12     Female
05    healthy       33     Female
```

To build a function that calculate the percentage of healthy people by healthy+un_health

```
def health_rate(healthy, un_healthy,age){
    if (age >= 15):
        if (gender == "Male"):
            return rateMale= (count(healthy)/count(healthy)+count(un_healthy))
        Else
            return rateFemale= (count(healthy)/count(healthy)+count(un_healthy))
    Else 
        return print("underage");
```

and then just use .apply

but the logic isn't right, I still not get my desired output
I want to return Male rate and Female rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) (`df` your dataframe):

```
df = df[df.Age >= 15].pivot_table(
    index="status", columns="Gender", values="ID",
    aggfunc="count", margins=True, fill_value=0
)
```

Result for your sample dataframe:

```
Gender      Female  Male  All
status                       
healthy          1     1    2
un_healthy       0     1    1
All              1     2    3
```

If you want percentages:

```
df = (df / df.loc["All", :] * 100).drop("All")
```

Result:

```
Gender      Female  Male        All
status                             
healthy      100.0  50.0  66.666667
un_healthy     0.0  50.0  33.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

[`df[col_name].value_counts(normalize=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts) gives you the proportions for the desired column. Here's how you can parameterize it:

```py
def health_percentages(df, col_name):
    return df[col_name].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
```

Example:

```py
data = [ [1, 'healthy',16,'M'], [2, 'un_healthy',14,'F'], [3, 'un_healthy', 22, 'M'],[4, 'healthy', 12, 'F'],[5, 'healthy', 33, 'F']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','status', 'Age', 'Gender'])
print(df)
print(health_percentages(df, 'status'))

#output:
   ID      status  Age Gender
0   1     healthy   16      M
1   2  un_healthy   14      F
2   3  un_healthy   22      M
3   4     healthy   12      F
4   5     healthy   33      F

healthy       60.0
un_healthy    40.0
```